# Rendering a program icon to the Image Control using TPL

Tags: c#, wpf, behavior, task-parallel-library

Hi i'm trying to create an Interactivity.Behavior to load a program's icon in the background. The following is the code but it gave me The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it..

```
protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Url))
        {
            Icon ico = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(Url);
            if (ico != null)
            {

               taskScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
                                                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                                                ico.ToBitmap().Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);
                                                ms.Position = 0;
                                                BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                                                bi.BeginInit();
                                                bi.StreamSource = ms;
                                                bi.EndInit();
                                                return bi;
                                            }).ContinueWith((t) => AssociatedObject.Source = t.Result, taskScheduler);




            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPF objects (anything that descends from [DispatcherObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherobject.aspx)) are thread-affine -- normally they can only be used on the thread that created them. This includes [BitmapImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.aspx) objects. If you create the BitmapImage on a background thread, then it can only be used from that background thread -- which means that the UI thread will get an error when it tries to display the bitmap.

However, BitmapImage descends from [Freezable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.freezable.aspx). Freezable has a [Freeze](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms557735.aspx) method that will make the instance read-only. And per the "[Freezable Objects Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509.aspx)" on MSDN:

> A frozen Freezable can also be shared across threads, while an unfrozen Freezable cannot.

So if you add a call to `bi.Freeze();` just before you return the image from your background task, then you should be able to use the image successfully from your UI thread.

Comment: THanks.. i learn something new today... ;)

however...i tried putting the AssociatedObject.Source = bi in the Task's Action delegate and using Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ...., CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, taskScheduler); and it works also.... what is the difference?

Comment: If you start a task using `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext`, you're running it in the current thread. You might as well not use a task at all.

Answer (score 0):

Although you are using CurrentSynchronizationContext, give it a try if may have to be run  on the `Dispatcher` of the icon....

```
    ico.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
         new Action(
           () =>
           {
              ico.ToBitmap().Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png); 
              ///rest of the code that uses `ms`.
           }));
```

**Suggestion**: Why arent you using `Priority Binding` and `Binding.IsAsync` for slow loading images....

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/wpf/thread/b3dc9baa-4cf6-49ed-a316-b9fb1cd29516